# Azure Verizon CDN - 100% Cache CONFIG_NOCACHE

Tags: azure, caching, cdn, cache-control, azure-cdn

I set up an Azure Verizon Premium CDN a few days ago as follows:

**Origin**: An Azure web app (.NET MVC 5 website)
**Settings**: Custom Domain, no geo-filtering
**Caching Rules**: standard-cache (doesn't care about parameters)
**Compression**: Enabled
**Optimized for**: Dynamic site acceleration
**Protocols**: HTTP, HTTPS, custom domain HTTPS
**Rules**: Force HTTPS via Rules Engine (if request scheme = http, 301 redirect to https://{customdomain}/$1)

So - this CDN has been running for a few days now, but the ADN reports are saying that nearly 100% (99.36%) of the cache status is "CONFIG_NOCACHE" (Description: "The object was configured to never be cached in accordance with customer-specific configurations residing on the edge servers, so the response was served via the origin server.") A few (0.64%) of them are "NONE" (Description: "The cache was bypassed entirely for this request. For instance, the request was immediately rejected by the token auth module, or the client request method used an uncacheable request method such as "PUT".") Also, in the "Cache Hit" report, it says "0 hits, 0 misses" for every day. Nothing is coming through the "HTTP Large" side, only "ADN".

I couldn't find these exact messages while searching around, but I've tried:

- Updating cache-control header to max-age, public (ie: cache-control: public,max-age=1209600)
- Updating the cache-control header to max-age (cache-control: max-age=1209600)
- Updating the expires header to a date way in the future (expires: Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT)
- Using different browsers so the request cache info is different. In Chrome, the request is "cache-control: no-cache" in my browser. In Firefox, it'll say "Cache-Control: max-age=0". In any case, I'd assume the users on the website wouldn't have these same settings, right?
- Refreshing the page a bunch of times, and looking at the real time report to see hits/misses/cache statuses, and it shows the same thing - CONFIG_NOCACHE for almost everything.
- Tried running a "worldwide" speed test on https://www.dotcom-tools.com/website-speed-test.aspx, but that had the same result - a bunch of "NOCACHE" hits.
- Tried adding ADN rules to set the internal and external max age to 864000 sec (10 days).
- Tried adding an ADN rule to ignore "no-cache" requests and just return the cached result.

So, the message for "NOCACHE" says it's a node configuration issue... but I haven't really even configured it! I'm so confused. It could also be an application issue, but I feel like I've tried all the different permutations of "cache-control" that I can. Here's an example of one file that I'd expect to be cached:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

Ultimately, I would hope that most of the requests are being cached, so I'd see most of the requests be "TCP Hit". Maybe that's incorrect? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I eventually figured out this issue. Apparently Azure Verzion Premium CDN ADN platform has "bypass cache" enabled by default.

To disable this behavior you need to configure additional features to your caching rules.

Example:

IF Always
Features:
**Bypass Cache Disabled**
Force Internal Max-Age Response 200 864000 Seconds
Ignore Origin No-Cache 200

Comment: To clarify, does bypassing the cache allow one to overwrite the cache-control headers? I cannot find good documentation on adding cache-control to Verizon Premium CDN anywhere. It looks like this rule will set a cache-control header of keep for 864000 seconds. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ClaytonRothschild, yes - that's right. This overwrites cache control headers and ignores requests that say not to cache it - the bottom two rules. Also, I agree that the documentation of the internals is very light.